# Find a counterexample that the space of invariant and coinvariant is not isomorphic.

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, lie-algebras

I am thinking about the following problem:

> For a representaion $V$ of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, define the space of *coinvariants* by $V_{\mathfrak{g}}=V/\mathfrak{g}V$, where $\mathfrak{g}V$ is the subspace spanned by $x\cdot v,~x\in \mathfrak{g},v\in V$.
>
> And $V^{\mathfrak{g}}=\{v\in V:x\cdot v=0,~\forall x\in \mathfrak{g}\}$.
>
> If $V$ is completely reducible, then $V^{\mathfrak{g}}\cong V_\mathfrak{g}$. 
>    (Solved.)
>
> In general, it does not hold. (Hint: take $\mathfrak{g}=\mathbb{R}$).

I want to find a counterexample for this.

Maybe it will work if I find some example which is representation of $\mathbb{R}$, but not completely reducible. However, I failed even though with google.

Comment: The condition for invariants is $x\cdot v=0$ surely?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sorry for the typo. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume $\mathfrak{g}=\Bbb R$ means that $\frak g$ is the one-dimensional
Abelian real Lie algebra. So a representation of $\frak g$ consists of a real vector space $V$ together with an endomorphism $\phi$ of $V$.
The invariants are $\ker\phi$ and the coinvariants are $V/\textrm{Im}\,\phi$. These are certainly isomorphic when $V$ is finite-dimensional
but there are easy examples in the infinite-dimensional case where
$\phi$ is injective but not surjective.

Comment: Could you explain why $\phi^2=0$?

Comment: I don't think I can...

Comment: If the hint is wrong, could you give a counterexample without $\mathfrak{g}=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Sorry, I think the invariant is not $\ker \phi$.

Comment: @LeoGardon The Lie algebra is $\Bbb R u$, and $u\cdot v=\phi(u)$. So the invariants are $\ker\phi$ surely?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the vector space $V$ of finitely supported real sequences, i.e., $(v_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \in V$ if $v_j=0$  for $j \geq n_0$., for some $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\mathfrak{g}=R$ act like $r * (v_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}=(rv_{i+1})_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$. This is clearly a representation.

Then $V_{\mathfrak{g}}=V$; on the other hand $V^{\mathfrak{g}}=(a,0,0 \ldots 0), a \in \mathbb{R}$. Hint( Take a basis to see this)

Comment: Why $V_{\mathfrak{g}}=V$? I think you mean $V\cong V_{\mathfrak{g}}$.